# Fastest solution for scraping text rendered by javascript in Python

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I am relatively new to scraping and am trying to scrape this site (and many, many like it): http://www.superiorcourt.maricopa.gov/docket/CriminalCourtCases/caseInfo.asp?caseNumber=CR1999-012267

I'm using Python and Scrapy. My problem is that when I start up a scrapy shell and point it to this url, the response body is full of code I can't read,  e.g :

> c%*u9u\\'!    (vy!}vyO"*9u#$"v/!!*!"yJZ*9u!##v/!"*!%y\\_*9u\\')"v/\\'*!#myJO*u9u$)}vy}vy9CC*Ve^SdY_^uvkT_Se]U^dKju"&#$)\\')&vMK9u)}&vy}MKju!\\'$#)(#    (!#vMuvmy\\:*Ve^SdY_^uCy\\y

The information I actually want to scrape does not appear to be accessible.

I believe this is a javascript problem, and have confirmed that using tools others have suggested before, like Selenium, renders the page correctly. My problem is that I will need to scrape several million of these sites, and don't believe that a browser-based solution is going to be fast enough.

Is there a better way to do this? I do not need to click any links on the page (I have a long list of all the URLs I want to scrape), or interact with it in any other way. Is it possible that the response body contains a JSON code I could parse?

Comment: take a look at          https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio

Comment: Easy, run Scrapy with phantomjs.

Comment: darn javascript obfuscation. I'll bet that, even if you solved the obfuscation problem, that it's loading the stuff with JS. … except that it's not? Disabling JS in Safari is still loading the entire page content. Hmm. Oh, there's the obfuscated JS. Still, odd…

Comment: Current status: browsers (even with JS disabled) appear get both obfuscated JS *and* HTML, while `cURL`, at least, is only getting the obfuscated JS. I've now been blocked from that server, so my usefulness is over for tonight.

Comment: you need to decode gzip, IMO.

Comment: I tried to use the simple phantomjs script in their quick start guide to render a picture of the page and got nothing... maybe Hawken is right and this is not all a js thing?

Comment: PS the phantomjs error is: Resource request error: QNetworkReply::NetworkError(OperationCanceledError)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to wait for the javascript data to load I'd use [ScrapyJS](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash).

If you need to interact with javascript elements on the website maybe use Scrapy + [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) + [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/). the latter is usually a more popular choice because it's easier to learn and can do more but it's slower

Comment: Thanks. I've been working on a splash based solution, but having trouble getting it to install on my machine. I think there's some dependency I'm missing. Will keep at it.